# Scrollable table unobtrusive script

Tags: javascript, css, tablelayout

Here is nice piece of code that works fair in all browsers: http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Since there are things that need to be computed for every particular table (extra space for scrollbar, fixed width for every cell), I'd like to create a javascript that modifies the table to make it scrollable.

Such scripts already exist, i.e. http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-scrollable-table-plugin/
but all of them need to specify the height of the table. I'd like to extract the height from CSS to make the script unobtrusive.

If I write the height as inline style, all browsers can read the `table.style.height` property. But when external style is used

```
<style>
  .scrollTable { display: block; overflow: hidden; height: 200px; }
</style>
```

only Firefox can read the `offsetHeight/clientHeight` property as expected. Other browsers can't change table layout to block, I guess.

The only thing that I figured out is to read external CSS

```
function getCSS(rule,prop) {
  if(!(document && document.styleSheets)) return;
  var result="", ds = document.styleSheets;
  for(var i=0; i<ds.length; i++) {
    var r = getCSS1(ds[i],rule,prop);
    if(r) result = r;
  }
  return result;
}
function getCSS1(sheet,rule,prop) {
  var rules = sheet.cssRules? sheet.cssRules: sheet.rules;
  var result = "";
  for(var i=0; i<rules.length; i++) {
    var r = rules[i].selectorText.toLowerCase();
    if(r.indexOf(rule)==-1) continue;
    if(r.lastIndexOf(rule)!=r.length-rule.length) continue;
    var p = rules[i].style[prop];
    if(p) result = p;
  }
  return result;
}

var height = getCSS(".scrollTable","height");
```

But the height might be specified otherwise: by id, another class or inherited, so I am probably in wrong way. Is there any other way how to guess the table height? I am about to give up.

---

**In short**

I want this code

```
<script src="scrollTable.js"></script> // load the script
<style> .scrollTable { height: 200px; } // set the CSS
<table class="scrollTable">...</table> // script should do all the tricks
```

My script can do all the tricks except for get the table height. How to extract it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not enclose the `<table>` in a `<div>`? This way you should be able to the get the `<div>` height even if it's in an external CSS.

Comment: But the DIV's height is adjusted according to TABLE's height. Script can enforce fixed height to the DIV, but how to obtain the value in an unobtrusive way? TABLE's CSS height is ignored.

Comment: Here you go the bounty, since no one solved my problem and your solution was the most cunning. (I solved it a couple of days ago with inline CSS.)

Answer (score 1):

With **jQuery** you can use `.css()` function:

```
table_height = $("table.scrollTable").css("height");
```

This will return the height of your table including `px`. So you can extract only the number with some other javascript function.

Comment: Not working. Returns the same value as clientHeight (see other answers).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery (you did mention a jQuery plugin), you can calculate the height of an element using `$('table.selector').height()`.

Comment: Alas, not working. As I tested, IE and Chrome ignores the height property in CSS, the $('table.selector').height() returns the same value like offsetHeight

Answer (score 0):

Is getComputedStyle the answer ? See here : http://blog.stchur.com/2006/06/21/css-computed-style/

Comment: No, the computed style in non-FF browser is auto height in pixels. I think the problem is the table layout, height seems to work only in block layout. Explicit block layout forced to table does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

`document.getElementById("ID").clientHeight`

It worked for me in IE8 and Chrome when I tested `height` set via

- html
- inline style
- style sheet

Here's what I did:

```
<table height="350" id="one">
<table> 

<table style="height:400px;" id="two">
<table> 

<table class="height" id="three">
<table>
```

and

```
alert(document.getElementById("one").clientHeight);

alert(document.getElementById("two").clientHeight);

alert(document.getElementById("three").clientHeight);
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/h9B2j/

**EDIT**

Something else must be interfering with the code, I think, as

`document.getElementById("").clientHeight;`

works for me even without the height being set.

See **another example** here: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/h9B2j/2/

Comment: Not working. Try to add multiple rows to the table with greater total height than specified in CSS. clientHeight works as min-height in non-FF.

Comment: It should work, @Jan Turoň.  It works for me. See the above edit.

Comment: try to set the height to 10px, add some TRs and see if clientHeight is 10px - it is not in my tests. If you find any workaround the bounty is yours.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do.  A `table` will auto expand when rows are added, no matter what the `height` is... if the rows are bigger than the height.  For instance a `10px` high table will probably never remain `10px` once you start adding rows, given normal text height, etc.

Comment: I am trying to make Scrollable table unobtrusive script - see the title. It's not true that table will auto expand - see the content of my question. Even if it will, no matter, I can make workaround script. The key information I need is to obtain the table height specified in external CSS. Your example does not work if table auto expands.